# Argo workflow curl doesn't return http code

Tags: curl, http-headers, argo-workflows

I have Argo workflow

```
script:
  image: curlimages/curl:latest
  command:
    - sh
  source: >
    http_response=$(curl -X DELETE -w "%{http_code}" -o /mnt/out/rest_output.txt https://myurl/{{workflow.parameters.id}} -H "Authorization:Bearer {{inputs.parameters.token}}")
    echo $http_response > /mnt/out/http_response.txt
  volumeMounts:
    - name: out
      mountPath: /mnt/out
volumes:
  - name: out
    emptyDir: { }
```

to make call REST service.
The problem is that http_response returns empty string even when service returns 400 in curlimage.
What could be a problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I found the magic. When I have rewrote command like this

```
echo $(curl -X DELETE -w "%{http_code}" -o /mnt/out/rest_output.txt https://myurl/{{workflow.parameters.id}} -H "Authorization:Bearer {{inputs.parameters.token}}") > /mnt/out/http_response.txt
```

http code appears on output.